# Python: Syntax error, invalid syntax, array edit

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to implement the following code, but keep receiving a syntax error on the last line of the code. However I can't find the mistake. In my view it works exactly the same as the code before. 
Thanks a lot for any help!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N=100
D=2

X=np.random.randn(N,D)

#Center first 50 points at (-2,-2)'
X[:50,:] =X[:50,:] - 2 * np.ones((50,D))

#Center last 50 points at 2,2
X=[50:,:]=X[50:,:] + 2 * np.ones((50,D))
```

Comment: Can you add the exact text of the error to your question?

Comment: Can you spot there error here? `X=[50:,:]=X[50:,:] `

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know how I didn't recognize it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "=" to much at the last line.

```
X[50:,:]=X[50:,:] + 2 * np.ones((50,D))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N=100
D=2

X=np.random.randn(N,D)

#Center first 50 points at (-2,-2)'
X[:50,:] =X[:50,:] - 2 * np.ones((50,D))

# #Center last 50 points at 2,2
X[50:,:]=X[50:,:] + 2 * np.ones((50,D))
```